# for loop step based on current value

Tags: php

I've set the above loop which displays integers.

I'm looking to be able to set the step based on the value (`$i`)

```
$min = 100;
$max = $1000;

$step_values = array(
    900 => 100,
    100000 => 1000
);

for($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i += 100) {
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.' Credits (&pound;'.number_format($credit_cost,2).' = &pound;'.number_format(($credit_cost * $i)).')</option>';
}
```

Currently the loop steps by 100, but i'd like to have it step by the value in the `$step_values` array based on the key which is the current value of `$i`

For example, the step is `100` for values of 900 and below and the step is `1000` for values of 10000 and below as per the array but I was unsure on how to do the 'up to' part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you need to search for the increment each time, I've moved the increment inside the loop and at each loop it will look through the step values list and check it against the current value...

```
$min = 100;
$max = 10000;    // Remove the $ and for testing I've increased this

$step_values = array(
    200 => 100,
    300 => 200,
    2500 => 500,
    5000 => 1000,
    10000 => 2000    
);
$credit_cost = 1;   // Test value
for($i = $min; $i <= $max;) {
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.' Credits (&pound;'.number_format($credit_cost,2).' = &pound;'.number_format(($credit_cost * $i)).')</option>';
    foreach ( $step_values as $limit => $increment )    {
        if ( $i <= $limit )  {
            $i+=$increment;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs...

```
<option value="100">100 Credits (&pound;1.00 = &pound;100)</option>
<option value="200">200 Credits (&pound;1.00 = &pound;200)</option>
<option value="300">300 Credits (&pound;1.00 = &pound;300)</option>
<option value="500">500 Credits (&pound;1.00 = &pound;500)</option>
<option value="1000">1000 Credits (&pound;1.00 = &pound;1,000)</option>
<option value="1500">1500 Credits (&pound;1.00 = &pound;1,500)</option>
<option value="2000">2000 Credits (&pound;1.00 = &pound;2,000)</option>
<option value="2500">2500 Credits (&pound;1.00 = &pound;2,500)</option>
<option value="3000">3000 Credits (&pound;1.00 = &pound;3,000)</option>
<option value="4000">4000 Credits (&pound;1.00 = &pound;4,000)</option>
<option value="5000">5000 Credits (&pound;1.00 = &pound;5,000)</option>
<option value="6000">6000 Credits (&pound;1.00 = &pound;6,000)</option>
<option value="8000">8000 Credits (&pound;1.00 = &pound;8,000)</option>
<option value="10000">10000 Credits (&pound;1.00 = &pound;10,000)</option>
```

Let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: this is very nice code, works great thank you! i'm trying to list the values `100, 200, 300, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 8000, 10000` but think i've missed something (its been a long day!) i've changed step values to this `200 => 100,
     500 => 200,
     1000 => 1000,
     5000 => 2000,
     10000 => 2000`

Comment: Not sure how you get those figures as when the value is 500, you say the increment would be 200 (500 => 200) and so it would then be 700. Then it would move to increments of 1000, so this would make 1700.  Can you check the figures your expecting.

Comment: ah, no sorry. thats no the figures i have, thats what i;m trying to achieve